# Shebang followed by rm command not a self deleting script

Tags: bash

I am referring this tutorial http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html#AEN226 on bash to further improve my knowledge but I can't seem to get to delete my script with the script commands mentioned in the website. Am I doing something wrong or the code itself is wrong?

```
#!/bin/rm
# Self-deleting script.

# Nothing much seems to happen when you run this... except that the file disappears.

WHATEVER=85

echo "This line will never print (betcha!)."

exit $WHATEVER  # Doesn't matter. The script will not exit here.
                # Try an echo $? after script termination.
                # You'll get a 0, not a 85.
```

I have also tried,

```
#!/bin/rm -f
```

that too, does not work.

Comment: Code is fine, works for me. How exactly are you executing the script? If you call it as `bash MyScript.sh` (instead of `./MyScript.sh`), that will override the shebang. (Or maybe you have a strange system where `/bin/rm` does not exist?)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that but makes sense. I should probably delete the question.

Comment: instead of deleting, u may ask DevSolar to post it as an answer, and accept it. It will certainly help someone facing similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang notation indicates the interpreter to be used when the script is executed as-is (`./MyScript.sh`).

If you *explicitly* state the interpreter -- as in, `bash MyScript.sh` -- that overrules the shebang line. So I am guessing that is what happened here.